# Camera text recognition reads the text continuously

Tags: java, android

How to use the camera when reading the text for the first time does not repeat and does not rotate the text continuously?
This code is constantly reading the same text.

```java
textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
    @Override
    public void release() {

    }

    @Override
    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
        final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
        if(items.size() != 0)
        {
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = 0;i<items.size();++i)
                    {
                        TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                        stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    }
                    textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should either stop the recognition after you find text or store the text you find and compare it with the new detection to see if it's different or not.

Comment: Thanks for comment, can you specifically correct this code I posted?

Comment: What's your use-case ?